# Hangman game what to put to keep code running

Tags: python-3.6

This is my code for a hangman game. I cannot figure out how to check if the letter that they enter is in the word and then check if the sequence of letters is equal to the letters in the word.

Thanks for the help.

```
import sys
import random
answers = [ a long list of possible answers all correctly formatted :d ]

again =""
num = 0

win = True

while again == "":
    contin = input("""
            ...Hangman...
            enter to play
            ['stop'] to stop
""")

    again = contin.title()
    if again == "":
        num = random.randint(0,len(answers)-1)
        word = answers[num]
        tries = len(word)+10
        print(word)



        while   :
            guessmessage ="guess a letter.... You have ",tries,"tries: "
            guess = input(guessmessage)


            if tries != len(word)+10:

                for letter in word:

                    if guess != letter:
                        print(" ")
                        tries = tries - 1

                    else:
                        print(letter)
                        tries = tries - 1

        else:

            sys.exit("You Have Ran Out Of Attempts..... Better Luck Next Time!")

else:
    sys.exit("You Have Quit The Game! :(  ")
```

Comment: Please be more specific on what part you are having trouble with.  What is "going" wrong in your code.  Narrow down your issue for us so we, as volunteers know where to start looking, and in fact are motivated to look.   Please review: Please read and follow the following docs before posting your next question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, then `edit` your question.  Thanks for helping us help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you mean by *"check if the sequence of letters is equal to the letters in the word"*. Please give an example of what you want to achieve on that part.

As for checking if a *'letter'* is in the *'word'* to be guessed, you can simply do it with this code:

```
answer = "hangman"
guess = 'a'

if guess in word:
    print("Letter", guess, "is in the answer.")
else:
    print("Letter", guess, "is not in the answer.)
```

I just used if-else as an example but basically the syntax is as straightforward as `letter in word`.